# SAS: Creating a macro variable containing all months between two dates

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro variable in date `yyyymm` format, where `yyyy` is `year` like `2020` and `mm` is month like `02`, as shown below:

```
%let m=202002;
```

How can I construct a macro variable `m_new` having as many months in the past as we specify? For eg; if `num` is 5, we get a macro variable having that many months from the past including the one itself. Something like

```
%put &m_new.
    202002 202001 201912 201911 201910
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a macro (or just a %DO loop if you are already inside a macro).

The issue is you need to convert YYYYMM values into an actual date.  Then you can use INTNX() to generate the new dates and format them with YYMMN6. format to generate new YYYMM strings.

```
%macro months(start,number);
%local i date ;
%let date=%sysfunc(inputn(&start.01,yymmdd8));
%do i=0 %to %eval(&number-1); %sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-&i),yymmn6)%end;
%mend ;

%put %months(start=202002,number=5);
```

Comment: Incidentally, I was facing exactly the problem you have answered, but with date in `date9.` format, so your solution solved it straight away. Thank you.

Comment: If the start data is in style that DATE informat can read you can skip the INPUTN() step and use a date literal.  `"&start"d`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
%let m=202002;
%let n=5;

data _null_;
   length dt_c $ 500;
   dt = input ("&m.", yymmn6.);
   dt_c = put(dt, yymmn6.);
   do i = 1 to &n.-1;
      dt_c = catx(' ', dt_c, put(intnx('month', dt, -i), yymmn6.));
   end;
   call symputx('m_new', dt_c);
run;

%put &m_new.;
```

Result:

```
202002 202001 201912 201911 201910
```

Comment: Thanks draycut for your answer.